Hide Attributes with sphinx-autodoc2
I have  classes defined with the @dataclass decorator. This means that they look like this:
@dataclass
class myclass:
    """Some class

    :param first_param: some description
    :param second_param: some description

    first_param: str
    second_param: int

    def __post_init__(self):
        etc...

This makes sphinx-autodoc2 document the first_param and second_param twice within the class: once inside the Parameters list, and once below this as individual attributes.
How can I hide the duplicate listing of these parameters?
